# Is it possible to add some vertical lines to a Waterfall Chart in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I'm using a (modified) Waterfall Chart to show progress while tracking IT Certifications (amount) on a monthly basis.  This is intended to be an ongoing work but all I'll be tracking is the last 12 month's of activity (fiscal year).  I'm tracking results for several individual sister companies within a region.

I'd like to add some vertical lines to visually separate quarterly results (vertical line between March/April, June/July, September/October, and December/January.

I tried it manually, but some results (like Region's) cause the "Y" axis to widen and this effectively causes misalignment with the vertical lines.

This is what the end result should look like:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the source data:

[image]

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question?  It isn't clear what data relates to the chart, what you tried to do, or what problem that caused.

Comment: Of course. How do I do it in this site? I searched for something like "add file" but so far I'm lost...

Comment: How about relevant screenshots?

Comment: Just adding vertical lines is simple: right click the relevant axis and select add major grid lines. Set the interval by adjusting the tick marks on the axis. Aligning them with the quarterly breakdown, however, would be more difficult. You would need to pad your data by adding an extra month to align it correctly.

Comment: I tried that but it adds all major grid lines and not only the "quarterly" ones I'm looking for. Thanks anyway for trying to help. Much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this by adding a data series as a combination XY chart.  The series points will use an x-value to match your required horizontal position and a 0 y-value (messes less with Excel's auto scaling "feature").  Then add vertical error bars for the data points matching the height you require and format to taste.

Here's an example with xy data points in blue and error bar in blue.

[image]

**EDIT:**

1. Add a small data table on one of your worksheets with X and Y coordinates for the points that will "anchor" your vertical lines.  In the example I used X{2.5,4.5,6.5} and Y{0,0,0}.  You can adjust your X values to match wherever you want them to appear in the chart.  For the vertical, I prefer 0, because it doesn't usually require setting a max chart value.
2. Add a data series to your existing chart using the Y values above.
3. Select the new series and change the series chart type to XY/Scatter.
4. Go to the Select Data dialog box, select the new series and add your X values.
5. Select your new data series and insert Error bars.  Delete the horizontal error bars and set your vertical error bars to an appropriate value.
6. Format the data points and error bars to taste.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a step by step explanation? I've been working my excel magic for years focused mainly on functions, formulas, a couple basic charts, etc. It's not been until recently I've been tasked to turn all that into Dashboards, Balanced Scorecards, combination charts, etc. whatever management requires but IT is too busy to build immediately. I will add a sample file...